# Reading XML and Creating Multiple Tables

Tags: java, sql, xml, jmx

I have an XML input file that looks like:

```
<mbean className="OperatingSystem">
    <attribute>
        <attributeName>Arch</attributeName>
        <formatter>STRING</formatter>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <attributeName>ProcessCpuLoad</attributeName>
        <formatType>PERCENT</formatType>
    </attribute>
</mbean>
```

I've created a POJO called 'Mbeans' that looks like:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "mbean")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Mbean
{
    @XmlElement(name = "attribute")
    private List<Attribute> attributes = null;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "className")
    private String className;

    public String getClassName() {
        return className;
    }
}
```

I can successfully unmarshall my XML File into this POJO and my application can use this object as needed. This input file tells me the information I need to pull from a particular MBean I have. Is there a way to create multiple tables based on the XML file, such that when I pull said information I can store that information into said table structure and then use JDBC to create SQL tables on my H2 database?

For example, I would like to create tables that look like:

```
+------------------------+
|        MBeans          |    
+------+-----------------+
|  ID  | MBeanName       |
+------+-----------------+
| 1    | OperatingSystem |
+------+-----------------+

+--------------------------------+
|        Attributes              |
+------+--------+----------------+
|  ID  | MbeanId| AttributeName  |
+------+--------+----------------+
| 1    |    1   | Arch           |
+------+--------+----------------+
| 2    |    1   | ProcessCpuLoad |
+------+--------+----------------+

+------------------------------------+
|        OperatingSystem.Arch        |
+------+--------+------------+-------+
|  ID  | MbeanId| AttributeId| Value |
+------+--------+------------+-------+
| 1    |    1   |    1       | amd64 |
+------+--------+------------+-------+
| 2    |    1   |    1       | amd64 |
+------+--------+------------+-------+

+------------------------------------+
| OperatingSystem.ProcessCpuLoad     |
+------+--------+------------+-------+
|  ID  | MbeanId| AttributeId| Value |
+------+--------+------------+-------+
| 1    |    1   |    2       | 0.009 |
+------+--------+------------+-------+
| 2    |    1   |    2       | 0.0691|
+------+--------+------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first make :

- A method mapping `className` into table name `public String getTableName(String className)`
- A method mapping `attributeName` into clomun name `public String getColumnName(String attributeName)`
- A method mapping `formatType` or `formatter` into the database types `public String getType(String formatType)`

and then

```
public void createTable(Mbean bean) throws SQLException{
    String sql = getCreateTable(bean);
    // execute SQL using JDBC...
}

private String getCreateTable(Mbean bean) {
    String sqlStart = "CREATE TABLE " + getTableName(bean.getClassName()) + " (" ;
    return bean.getAttributes().stream()
        .map(attribute -> mapToColumn(attribute))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ", sqlStart, ")"); // what about primary key?
}

private String mapToColumn(Attribute a) {
    return getColumnName(a.getName()) + " " + getType(/*it depends*/);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! While I did not implement it the way you suggested, your solution gave me an idea. I created an object called Table with Rows, and the columns of this table were {"ID", "MbeanID", "AttributeID", "Value"}. Then passed this object to a method called update, in a manner inspired by getCreateTable(), which would create the necessary sql tables if they did not already exist, or updated the existing tables with "insert" statements.